# How to create a marker that would be on a polyline, at a certain distance from another marker on the polyline- GoogleMaps API Javascript V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a marker at a certain distance form the starting point  on the polyline I already created.
(I have a polyline with start point and end point with markers at those points.I want to add markers at specific distances from the start point. I tried to use the method poly.GetPointsAtDistance(distance) but apparently it is not in use anymore. I have looked at different posts and google Maps Api but haven't succeeded to make it work.
I have

```
 var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
 map: map, 
 path: [location1, location2],
 strokeWeight: 7,
 strokeOpacity: 0.8,
 strokeColor: "#FFAA00"
});
```

I have the length of the polyline

```
 var line_length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(line.getPath());)
```

I have a function to create the marker:

```
 function createMarker(map, latlng, title){
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:latlng,
    map:map,
      title: title
      });
```

I would like to be able to create the marker by giving the distance (new_distance) From start point. 
In something like:

```
createMarker(map, line.GetPointAtDistance(new_distance), title);
```

Any suggestion to what to use to replace GetPointAtDistance

Comment: Just to clarify my question a bit more. What I would like is to be able to add a marker for example at line_length/4, or line_length/3...etc in a function that would look like this:  createMarker(map, line.GetPointAtDistance(line_length/3), title);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function .GetPointAtDistance is part of Mike Williams' [epoly library for v2](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm).  There is a version ported to v3 here: 
http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js

[example using it on v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

Code:

```
// === A method which returns a google.maps.LatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
              this.getPath().getAt(i),
              this.getPath().getAt(i-1)
            );
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1= this.getPath().getAt(i-2);
  var p2= this.getPath().getAt(i-1);
  var m = (metres-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng( p1.lat() + (p2.lat()-p1.lat())*m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng()-p1.lng())*m);
}
```

requires [google.maps.geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you mind telling me how to get the pluggin to work with my app (it is a ruby on rails app) so I could use the function getPointAtDistance? I am a beginner, so the more detailed the steps, the better.

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot! I added the    google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
 and it did the trick